# Is there something like a class that can be implemented?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, abstract, multiple-inheritance

I'd like to write a 
**class X** (this) which 
**inherits from A** (base) can 
**execute the methods of B** (?) and must 
**implement the members of C** (interface).

Implementing A and C are not a problem. But since X cannot derive from multiple classes it seems impossible to have X inherit the logic of A and B. Note that A is the very important base class and B is almost a interface but contains executable behaviour. The reason why I don't want B to be an interface is because the behaviour is the same for every class that inherits or implements it.

**Do I really must declare B as an interface and implement the exact same 10 lines of code for each X that needs the behaviour of B?**

---

*2 months later*
I am currently learning C++ for using it in UE4 (Unreal Engine 4).
Since C++ is a lot less strict than C# it actually contains a <s>pattern</s> <s>implementation</s> <s>idom</s> term that describes this behaviour: These are called **mixin**s.
You can read a paragraph about the C++ mixin [here](http://www.bobtacoindustries.com/Content/Devs/CsToCpp-ASomewhatShortGuide.pdf) on page 9 (second paragraph).

Comment: Why dont you just inherit B from A or vice versa?

Comment: Why can you not use composition here? Delegate the methods of B to an instance of B... (It's very hard to talk about this sort of thing in such an abstract way. It would be more helpful if you'd give a concrete example.)

Comment: @k4rlsson Because not every X requires B (The dev should be able to implement it or not)

Comment: @noelwidmer So if B inherits A you can choose to inherit from B if you need it or A directly if you dont?

Comment: @k4rlsson What if D wants to implement B? E, F, G ... may also like to implement B?

Comment: @noelwidmer Do you mean that you want to inherit from B without inheriting from A in some cases?

Comment: @k4rlsson Yes, but B cannot be an interface because it contains executable logic. I think "dasblinkenlight" provided a very good solution...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do I really must declare `B` as an interface and implement the exact same 10 lines of code for each `X` that needs the behaviour of `B`?

Yes and no. You do need to make `B` an interface. But common method implementations should not be duplicated across all implementations of the interface. Instead, they should go into a class extension for interface `B`:

```
public interface B {
    void MethodX();
    void MethodY();
}
public static class ExtensionsB {
    public static void MethodZ(this B b) {
        // Common implementations go here
    }
}
```

Extension methods provide a way to share implementations "horizontally", without having your classes inherit from a second class. Extension methods behave as if they were regular methods of the class:

```
class X : A, B {
    public void MethodX() {...}
    public void MethodY() {...}
}
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    var x = new X();
    x.SomeMethodFromA();
    x.MethodX(); // Calls method from X
    x.MethodY(); // Calls method from X
    x.MethodZ(); // Calls method from ExtensionsB
}
```

Comment: That is perfect! I would like you to add the "class" attribute on your extension class. And I want to note that the extension method can be called from within the class using this.Extension(). Calling Extension() within the class does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet would be to require an instance of `B` in the constructor of `A` and then expose or call the methods of `B` as required:

```
public class X : A, C
{
    private readonly B _b;

    public X(B b)
    {
        _b = b;
    }
}
```

You'll find a lot of information on this sort of approach if you look up [Composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Comment: That would force the dev to implement (declare) B but I want the dev to allowed to choose (implement) by himself. As if B is an interface

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean; implementing and declaring aren't the same thing. It might be easier to recommend a solution if you give a concrete example. But composition is a pretty flexible approach.

Comment: Sorry for not providing a specific example. What I meant is that your X ALWAYS declares a field of B. But I want to be able to decide if my X uses (implements) B or not. With the answer provided by "dasblinkenlight" I can now decide to implement B on my X or ignore it. If I choose to ignore it there won't be any field of B on my X.

Comment: You could just omit B from the constructor if the implementation doesn't require it. Either way, I'm glad you got an answer to your problem. :)

Comment: The private field would then point to null, hmm... I see your point and it might help someone. Although you would still be left with a useless pointer  for each instance that does not require B and the overloaded constructor taking in a B cannot be omited.

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean overload the constructor. I mean a separate implementation of X which doesn't include a reference to B at all. If it doesn't require B the logic of the class is going to be different so it should be a different implementation.

Comment: Alright, well I disgussed that with k4rlsson in the comments on the questions. What if D want's to implement B? Or E, F, G ...?

Comment: Any class which requires the functionality of B can have it injected in the constructor the same as X.

Comment: If I get you correctly (not sure) you want to create a second class with the additional field for B. I still don't understand how that could safe me from writing hunderst new classes. +1 for the great source btw

Comment: Well you're better off with hundreds of classes which each serve a specific function (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) than one massive one which tries to cover every scenario.

Comment: We are getting of topic here. What I wanted is something like an interface wich by all means is not a huge class that solves all cases. It should simply require the implementation of a single task from its derivers. Why should I create tons of new classes if they all share the same behaviour? It is against the idea of inheritance.

Comment: Yup, we're way off topic. It's quite difficult to ascertain the best solution without a concrete example of the problem. Again, glad you got the solution you were after.